# Как с помощью директивы &НаСервере у документа вывести номер?

Tags: 1с

Как правильно делать так, чтобы вывелся номер товара, который на скриншоте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал такой код:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ИскатьЗаказахПокупателей()
ЗаказыПокупателей = Документы.ЗаказПокупателя;
НомерТовара = "ЧПРТ-000004";
Сообщить(ЗаказыПокупателей.НайтиПоРеквизиту("Номер", НомерТовара));
КонецПроцедуры
```

Вот конфигурация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятен функционал Вашего кода. Номер - синоним, по факту там код или наименование

Comment: А что не получилось ? Какая ошибка ?